# Editing User Email Address

Tags: emails, permissions

I created a user group that has full permissions for User options in the CP, i.e. all the boxed ticked. However, they are not able to edit a user's email address.

When changing the email field and clicking Save it asks for password as usual, accepts it and closes the user form. However, the email does not change and there is no error message.

If I go in as Admin, it works fine, but not for any User Group, irrespective of the fact that their permissions include changing email addresses.

One possible clue is that these users were migrated from an older site and the email addresses have not yet been confirmed. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `Verify email addresses?` checked in User Settings. If, so the emails may not be getting saved. Settings desc: `Should new email addresses be verified before getting saved to user accounts? (This also affects new user registration.)`. If so, maybe temporarily disabling?

Comment: That is the case - I can override as Admin, but those with just User Permissions can not, hence the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "verify user email" setting will keep anyone other than the user or an Admin from changing an email address